# phantom does linebreak instead of invisible math mode character

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, line-breaking

I have the following two lines:

```
$\Rightarrow$ Generate $\mathbb{G}^n$ and check the existence of a homomorphism\\
from $\mathbb{G}^n$ to $\mathbb{G}$!
```

I want the second line to start exactly under the text of the first line, behind the $\Rightarrow$. So I wanted to use the \Rightarrow as a phantom character in front of the second line. Since \Rightarrow only works in math mode, I wrote:

```
$\Rightarrow$ Generate $\mathbb{G}^n$ and check the existence of a homomorphism\\
\phantom{$\Rightarrow$} from $\mathbb{G}^n$ to $\mathbb{G}$!
```

But I got this

[image: no phantom but linebreak]

instead of this (which I want):
[image: hack with white colored character]

I made the latter version with a white-colored character

```
\textcolor{white}{$\Rightarrow$} from $\mathbb{G}^n$ to $\mathbb{G}$!
```

But I want the character to be invisible, not just white. How can I achieve this?

And why is phantom behaving like this?

Note: \vphantom and \hphantom produce the same undesired result.

Comment: `$\phantom{\Rightarrow}$`

Comment: Note that `beamer` uses `\raggedright`, so ``\\`` implicitly executes `\par`. Thus the problem is exactly the same as in the question marked as duplicate. You can also cure the problem by using `\phantom` inside math mode.

Comment: I see. Maybe it would be a good idea to tag the older question with "phantom" and/or "line-break". I searched for phantom and linebreak but couldn't find that question.